# Specifying properties with annotations inside a Spring profile

Tags: java, spring

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a Spring profile that, when active, specifies some additional properties.

Let me explain it more thoroughly, I have got a bunch of Spring profiles that I use in tests. For my tests, I also have one `application.properties` file, nothing fancy. Now, I would like to tweak this properties file depending on the currently active profile.

Obviously, I can do that with creating another `application.properties` file, but with some suffix. I can also create a POJO with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Because I want only 1 or maybe 2 additional properties in my profile, a simple annotation is preferred by me. Creating a unique property file that is barely differing for each of my profiles just doesn't feel right.

I'm aiming for something like this:

`application.properties`:

```
some.property=true
some.other.property=false
.
.
.
last.property=1
```

A profile:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("main")
@Property("property.for.this.profile.only=true") // <-- THIS
public class MainProfile {

    // do something
}
```

Can I do that in some way? :)

Comment: if you use a dev profile for example, you can create a application-dev.properties file. Spring is configured to read the application.properties, then read the application-[profile].properties, and for properties in both files, the profile specific file takes precedence and "overwrites" the value specified in the application.properties file for that specific property

Comment: @experimentunit1998X right, okay, thanks. But, still, is it possible to do it by annotation (or some other, programmatic, way)? I feel like it's better to have 5 annotations specifying 5-10 properties in total rather than having 5 separate files doing that.

Comment: the only other way I know would be to pass it through the command line i think ie `-Dmy.value=something`

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring this shows the @TestPropertySource annotation that lets you specify names and values directly `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"foo=bar"})`

Comment: but that seems to only be for testing.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X thank you very much! It works :D I'm only really concerned with tests right now, so that suits me :) Obviously, I've seen that link too, but missed the information :( My bad, thank you for your time! :D